# Filename encoding broken after unzip on windows

Tags: linux, windows, zip

I zipped a directory on my linux server. Many files in the directory have german umlauts in their filename. The filesystem is ext3 and the system locale is set to de_DE.utf8.

I used the following command to create the zip file:

```
zip -r somezip.zip somefolder/
```

I transfered this file via WinSCP to my windows laptop and unzipped it. The issue: All filenames with german umlauts are broken. On my linux server the filenames are displayed correctly.

I assume that I made a mistake when i created the zip file.

Has someone any ideas how i can perserve the right filename encoding when I zip the files with the zip command on linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably caused by your Windows being configured in a latin-1 encoding.

I think the easiest way around it is to temporarily set your locale to iso-8859-15 and run zip again:

```
export LC_ALL=de_DE.iso885915
locale # Check that the locale was applied
zip -r somezip.zip somefolder/
export LC_ALL=de_DE.utf8 # Restore
```

If the first step fails because you don't have the locale installed, you can set it up with:

```
sudo locale-gen de_DE.iso885915
```